# Mutating a count of rows per group matching a subset condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I wish to mutate a new column called `SF_COUNT` which is a count per group (`ID`) of the number of rows per group where the column type contains '`SF`'

A reproducible example looks as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1234,1234,1234,4567,4567,4567,4567,8900,8900,8900),type = c('RF','SF','SF','RF','SF','SF','SF','RF','SF','SF'))
```

My final data frame looks like:

```
final_df <- data.frame(ID = c(1234,1234,1234,4567,4567,4567,4567,8900,8900,8900),type = c('RF','SF','SF','RF','SF','SF','SF','RF','SF','SF'), SF_COUNT = c(2,2,2,3,3,3,3,2,2,2))
```

How can I achieve this in dplyr please?

Comment: Your input example shows 'SF' as string instead of 'SJ'

Comment: @akrun thank you, I had a brain fade!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping by 'ID', get the `sum` of logical `vector` (`type == 'SF'`) in `mutate` to create the new column

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(SF_COUNT = sum(type == 'SF', na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

If it is a substring, then use `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
df <- df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(SF_COUNT = sum(str_detect(type, 'SF'), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: thanks again, I was trying all various types of sub-setting, add_count, nrows, you name it but I couldn't get it. Your example above is concise but you've also taken the time to explain the logic. Nice touch!